# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot'

Tags: windows, python-3.8, python-module

I'm on Windows and I work with python 3.8.
If I execute a python script where libraries need to be compiled, I will get the following error:

```
Failed to import ahead-of-time-compiled modules.
This is expected on first import.
Compiling modules and trying again.
This might take a minute.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\env\lib\site-packages\pymatting_aot\cc.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pymatting_aot.aot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatting_aot.aot
```

I already installed pymatting with pip.
Does anybody now a solution to solve this error?